# A little confused about constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
constexpr const int* address(const int& r)
{
   return &r;
}


int main()
{
   int x = 10;
   constexpr const int* p = address(x); //error

   _getch();
   return 0;
}
```

This is an error: "function call must have a constant value in a constant expression". Ok.

Two questions:

1. If 'x' is declared **static**, there are no errors. Why?
2. How is it possible to get a variable address during the compilation process? Aren't they allocated at run-time?

Answer (score 11):

> If 'x' is declared static, there are no errors. Why?

This is because there is always exactly one x in the program. It has an address (somewhere in the `.data` segment under normal conditions).

Confusingly, both `static` and `extern` keywords specify the storage duration as static (they differ in linkage)

> How is it possible to get a variable address during the compilation process? Aren't they allocated at run-time?

Variables with automatic, dynamic or thread [storage durations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) are allocated at runtime. Static duration variables are allocated by the compiler. (The linker and OS can change the location, but they know how to fix all the references when they do)

Answer (score 6):

A pointer to a variable with `static` storage duration *is* a `constexpr`. You can see this in the following program:

```
int main() {
    static int x;
    int y;
    constexpr int* px = &x; // Compilation is successful
    constexpr int* py = &y; // Compilation will fail
}
```

See https://ideone.com/lc9u3E

`px` is an *address constant expression*. Here's a standard reference:

[5.19p3]:

> An address constant expression is a prvalue core constant expression
>   of pointer type that evaluates to the address of an object with static
>   storage duration, to the address of a function, or to a null pointer
>   value, or a prvalue core constant expression of type std::nullptr_t.

Comment: Sorry, but bad quality answer. You just state fact without explaining why things are that way. Neither you address the second part of the question.

Comment: The fact that C++ insists on this is an adequate explanation, and I came up with a short snippet to demonstrate that. I intentionally avoided any references to *implementation*. Do downvote to express your opinion - it's what the process is for.

Comment: I've added some terminology and a C++ standard reference.

Comment: Leaving feedback on answer is the part of the process as well :) Feel free to ignore, but you give information to memorize, but not to understand. Standard indeed requires this, but this requirement is for a reason, not out of the blue. Giving OP clues to the reasoning helps to understand and learn discussed topic instead of memorizing set of rules. PS feels quite strange discussing teaching basics with Cambridge lector.

Answer (score 3):

The address of a variable with static storage duration is not known at compile time.
It is only known at link time.
A pointer to a variable with static storage duration can be used at compile time because the exact value of the address does not matter - pointer comparisons and casts are not allowed at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Because address of variable with static storage duration (global or local static) is known at compile time and doesn't change during program execution. Also there is exactly one object in the whole process.

Nothing of what has been said above is true for local variable. It is allocated in the stack frame, address of which differs. Also there can be several such frames at the same moment.

Answer (score 0):

To question 2:
"How is it possible to get a variable address during the compilation process? Aren't they allocated at run-time?"

x is placed on the stack, and it has a different address when the stack changes. This may happen if x is not declared in main(), but in some other function, which is called from different places. For example, try

```
#include <iostream>
constexpr const int* address(const int& r)
{
   return &r;
}


int f()
{
   int x = 10;

   const int* p = address(x);
   std::cout << "p=" << p << std::endl;
}

int g()
{
    int data[1000];
    f();
}

main()
{
   f();
   g();
   return 0;
}
```